# search pattern and set placeholder to a variable

Tags: regex, perl

i want to order people to groups according to a file.
The file looks like this:

```
group1 = john dave jim collin; 
group2 = abc def ghi jkl mno
      pqr stu vxz; 
group3 = marc;
```

So I have to match the person between the equal sign and the semicolon 
(newlines eventually in between, see group2) and ascribe to a group.

I've unsuccessfully tried the following:

```
my $person2ascr = "sarah";

open (grp_file, "<$group_file");
   # the line bellow will only match if the group list is in one line only
   while(<grp_file>) {my $grp = $1 if (/(.*)\s*=\s*.*\n*.*$person2ascr.*\n*.*;/i)};

   # the following line wont match any. Off course i close/open the file again
   while(<grp_file>) {my $grp = $1 if /(\w+)\s*=\s*(\w+)*\s*$person2ascr(\s+\w+)*\s*;/i};
```

But when i read the manuals i come up with the conclusion, I'm doing it right  :-/
Any help?

Comment: `while (<grp_file>)` only reads one line at a time. Since `$_` only contains one line, the regexp will never get a chance to process multiple lines. You need to keep reading until you see a `;`, concatenating the lines, and then do the match.

Comment: If you want to match across multiple lines you need to use the /s modifier.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$/=";";
my @grps = <DATA>;
s/\n+//g for@grps;
my $person2ascr = "ghi";
for(@grps) {
    say "group: $1" if /^([^=]+)=.*\b$person2ascr\b/;
}

__DATA__
group1 = john dave jim collin; 
group2 = abc def ghi jkl mno
      pqr stu vxz; 
group3 = marc;
```

**output:**

```
group:  group2
```

Comment: Can we avoid saving the file to an array? Maybe we can do it directly when reading the file ...

Comment: @user152037: It will be more complicated because we read one line at a time.

Comment: As-is this answer is incorrect in two ways: first, it sets $/ **GLOBALLY** and doesn't unset it; using local $/ inside a lexical block is the preferred approach; second, it sets $/ to ';' instead of ";\n" so each subsequent record will have a stray "\n" prepended to it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple way to read a record at a time from a file when the file has a well-defined end-of-record token.

```
#Enclosing braces to ensure local $/ stays very local
{
    #Use 3-arg open (safer)
    open my $fh, '<', $group_file or die "Can't open $group_file: $!";
    #Set "newline" separator to the end-of-record token
    local $/ = ";\n";
    while(my $record = <$fh>) {
        #$record will contain "groupN = some name or other;\n"
        chomp $record;
        #$record now contains "groupN = some name or other" without the trailing ";\n"
        my ($group, $data) = split / = /, $record, 2;
        #$group contains "groupN"; $data contains "some name or other"
        $grp = $group if $data =~ /$person2ascr/; #Add i modifier if you want case insensitive matching
    }
    #It's paranoid, but close _can_ fail
    close $fh or warn "Closing $group_file failed: $!";
}
```

Comment: to guard against = appearing in the data, you want `split / = /, $record, 2` (unlikely to be necessary with this data)

Comment: @ysth That's a pedantic thing to point out, but you're right. Added.

Comment: hi, great. Can u just add some comment to the line  ;local $/ = ";\n"; I do not know this structure yet. Any helpful link on it? Thx...

Comment: @user152037 http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-filehandles is probably the best place to read about it. `$/` is the variable which controls what perl considers the "end of line" token (it can be any string literal, and is a newline `"\n"` by default) and `local` makes it so the changes you make to `$/` inside the enclosing braces aren't visible anywhere else. When you read a line in perl with `<$fh>` it gives you the contents of the file, from the current position up to and including the next occurrence of the contents of `$/`.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is probably overkill.  It parses the group file and builds a full data-structure.  This may be appropriate, though, if you're querying against the group information repeatedly.  If you merely need to `grep` against the group file for a couple names, you probably do not want this solution as it is overkill for that.

I wrote a general parser for the groups file that returns two maps:  A mapping from name to group(s), and a mapping from group to names.

```
sub parse_name_groups
{
    my $file  = shift;          # file name of group file
    my %group_to_names;         # Hash mapping groups to lists of names
    my %name_to_groups;         # Hash mapping names to a list of groups
    my $group = "<UNKNOWN>";    # If we see a name outside of a group, assign it to <UNKNOWN>
    my $last_line_in_group = 0; # Flag: If we see a semicolon, this is the last line in a group.

    open my $fh, "<", $file
        or die "Cannot open group file \'$file\'\n";

    foreach my $line (<$fh>)
    {
        chomp $line;

        # Trim white space from front and back
        $line =~ s/^\s*//g;
        $line =~ s/\s*$//g;

        # Does line begin with a group specifier (ie. "group = ")?
        # If so, grab it and make it our current group.
        if ($line =~ s/^\s*(\S+)\s*=\s*//)
        {
            $group = $1;
        }

        # Does line have a semicolon?  Ignore it and everything
        # after.  Also, reset $group to <UNKNOWN> after this line.
        if ($line =~ s/;.*$//)
        {
            $last_line_in_group = 1;
        }

        # Split the rest of the line into a list of names
        # and make the name-to-group and group-to-name 
        # association.
        foreach my $name (split /\s+/, $line)
        {
            push @{ $group_to_names{ $group } }, $name;
            push @{ $name_to_groups{ $name  } }, $group;
        }

        if ($last_line_in_group)
        {
            $group = "<UNKNOWN>";
        }
        $last_line_in_group = 0;
    }

    close $fh;

    return ( \%group_to_names, \%name_to_groups );
}
```

And here's an example program that will look up a name in a group file, and tell you what group(s), if any, the name belongs to:

```
# Example program that looks up the group(s) associated with a name.  
# Usage:
# 
#   ./lookup_name group_file name

if ($#ARGV != 1)
{
    die "Usage: lookup_name group_file name\n";
}

my ( $file, $name ) = @ARGV;

my ($group_to_names, $name_to_groups) = parse_name_groups( $file );

my $groups = $name_to_groups->{ $name };

if (!defined $groups)
{
    print "$name does not belong to any groups\n";
} else
{
    print join("\n", @$groups), "\n";
}
```

Because the group file format wasn't fully specified, I made some judgment calls in my parser.  Specifically, if it sees something that looks like names before it sees a `group =` designation, it'll assign those names to the group `<UNKNOWN>`.  Likewise, if it sees a semicolon, any name it sees after that (starting on the line after) but before a `group =` gets assigned to the group `<UNKNOWN>`.

The code also treats the semicolon as an "end of line" indication.  Anything after the semicolon on the same line gets ignored.

There should be enough comments in the above code so that you can change these behaviors as needed for your application.

Comment: This is incredibly muddy & messy; in your efforts to avoid "hackish" idioms you've created a complicated and unnecessarily stateful solution. It's only "easier" in the sense that you need to know less perl, but it's vastly harder to comprehend on the basis of analysing the flow of what it actually does in order to achieve its function.

Comment: I don't see how it's all that complicated.  It does, however, actually parse the input and build a data structure that can be queried multiple times.  It's not _just_ a souped-up `grep`.  On a different note, I see I forgot to `close` my file.  I'll go fix that.

Comment: I'm not sure how to explain how this is complicated. It just is. You're using array manipulation, hashes, and capturing regexes to calculate something which can be very, very simply calculated using the correct line separator token, split, and a single matching regex.

Comment: I agree that if all you want to do is a souped up grep, then it's overkill.  If you want to keep referring to this data structure over and over, it's worth writing an actual parser that builds the data structure.  I changed the introduction to point out that my solution is overkill unless you actually want and can make use of the data structure it builds.

Comment: There is also the fact that if the set of targets is known ahead of time (i.e. this isn't being used by a long-lived process which is acting as an ersatz database in some fashion) then it's more efficient to check all the targets against the records one at a time instead of building a huge structure in memory and then checking everything against that.